# Jetty server allow all cross origins

Tags: java, javascript, http, jetty

I use jetty as java lib to run my local server, that has static content. How can I configure this server to allow all cross origins?
This is the code of my server:

```
        Server server = new Server(8087);

        Context staticContext = new Context(server, "/", 0);
        staticContext.setHandler(new ResourceHandler());
        staticContext.setResourceBase("./static");
        staticContext.setContextPath("/");
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```